# How to use POI/Geocoding search in skobbler

Tags: android, dictionary, skmaps

I want to search a places using string in skobbler. Like waze when i search for example "universal studios usa los angeles" then search the geo points of the universal will be given to me. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now the SDK offers 2 ways of searching:

- Addresses (geocoding) - via the MultiStepSearch component http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android#sec019
- Nearby POIs - via the NearBySearch component http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android#sec020

If I understand correctly you are looking for a "one line search" component (type your query in one line and Enter) - this is something that the SDK doesn't currently expose (we are working on it and in November we should have new developments regarding this).

Comment: What kind of update? (the API will remain unchanged for Q1/Q2 2015)

Comment: Are you still working on something like a "one line search" component, and if you are, do you have an ETA?

Comment: Yes - it is planned to be rolled out this fall, together with our consumer app update

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you don't really need to complicate things and rely on Skobbler for this, you can use the Android native geocoding API. The results are pretty accurate.

Note that the following runs on the UI thread, you may want to put it on an AsyncTask or whatever.

```
private void geocode (String address) {
    String baseUrl          = "";
    String [] splitAddress  = address.split ("[,\\s\\-:\\?]");
    for (int i = 0; i < splitAddress.length; i++) {
        if (i != 0) {
            baseUrl += "+";
        }
        baseUrl += splitAddress [i];
    }
    if (NetUtils.isOnline (MyActivity.this)) {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder (MyActivity.this);
        try {
            ProgressView.show (MyActivity.this, true);
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName (baseUrl, 1);
            if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
                Address addressResult = addresses.get (0);

                Log.e (MyActivity.this.class.getSimpleName () + " -- Address Found", address + " : " + addressResult.getLatitude () +  " : " + addressResult.getLongitude());

                launchRouteCalculation (addressResult.getLatitude (), addressResult.getLongitude ());
            } else {
                PopupUtils.show (MyActivity.this, null, "Could not find the destination.");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            ProgressView.dismiss ();
        }
    }
```